# Show() method will not show .gif in picturebox that was hidden a second ago

Tags: c#, class, hide, show

Okay so I have created a Flowlayoutpanel in which about 70 usercontrols, all squares of 50x50 pixels with an animated grass gif inside a picturebox inside of it. I want to make these hide-able but not be removed so there's a white space left. I've been able to do that quite consistently by just using `Hide()` and changing the background colour to be transparant so I don't have to hide the entire UserControl.

Problem comes up here, I want these gifs to reappear on a timer, so I've created a timer that references a method which just uses a `show()` again to show said gif and yet it refuses to do so if I create a seperate button to do so or not.

I have searched quite a bit but I think this is a problem only because I'm consistently missing something in my code so no other question really seems to answer my troubles. Because it's such a simple question I feel kind of embarrassed even asking it but oh well.

This is the timer event that calls the method in the other class

```
private void GrasTerugkeerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var instance = new GrasVeldUC();
            instance.TerugKeerGras();
        }
```

This is the events and methods I've set up to show and hide the picturebox that the gif is inside of

```
 public partial class GrasVeldUC : UserControl
    {
        public GrasVeldUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void GrasVeldUC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            PIBGrasUC.Hide();
        }

        private void PIBGrasUC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            PIBGrasUC.Hide();
        }
        public void TerugKeerGras()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 255, 255);
            PIBGrasUC.Show();
        }
    }
```

Now I expected this to just work and just show the picturebox again and yet whatever I tried, creating a seperate method that references the method in the other class, it would not work. And the method in the class "GrasVeldUC" does work I put a messagebox inside of it to test and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This: `var instance = new GrasVeldUC();` creates a new object, unrelated to those you already have inside the `Flowlayoutpanel`.  You need to 1. store the instance of a hidden control and show it  again on a `Timer.Tick` which knows how long this control has been hidden (hmmm)  2. Provide each UC object with its own timer which is enabled when the object is hidden ( :). 3. Same, but use a Task instead of a Timer and `await Task.Delay([timeout)];`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just toggle the `picturebox.visible` as needed.